# Notation for the sum of product indexing over all possible string of ternary digits of length $k$.

Tags: notation

Let $f_0, f_1$ and $f_2$ be three functions. 
What is a shorthand notation to write 
$$
\underbrace{f_0 f_0 \cdots f_0}_{\text{k times}} + \underbrace{f_0 f_0 \cdots f_0f_1}_{\text{k times}} + \cdots + \underbrace{f_2 f_2 \cdots f_2}_{\text{k times}} 
$$
In other words, the sum of the product indexing over all possible string of ternary digits of length $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a general base $b$.
Your case is
$b=3$.

Let
$R_b(n, m)$
be the $m-th$ digit
of $n$ written in base $b$,
with $m=0$ being the
units digit.
Computationally,
$R_b(n, m)
=\mod(\lfloor \frac{n}{b^m} \rfloor, b)
$,
where $\mod(u, v)$
is the remainder when
$u$ is divided by $v$.

Then,
if you have $b$ functions
$f(i)$
for $i=0$ to $b-1$,
the sum could be
$\sum_{m=0}^{b^k-1} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}
f(R_b(m, i))
$.

Essentially,
for all the $k$-digit numbers
in base $b$,
extract the digits
and use them to choose the proper
$f(i)$.

Nothing was said about
any other parameters
for the $f(i)$.